# Doxygen-generated qhc files show garbled in Qt Creator's documentation browser

Tags: qt, qt-creator, doxygen

I'm trying to se set up Doxygen to generate qhc files for integration with Qt Creator. While the HTML documentation looks fine, the qhc docs show up like this in Qt Creator's documentation browser:

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04, Doxygen 1.8.13 and Qt Creator 4.3.1.

Comment: Here's the doxygen conf I'm using: https://pastebin.com/ueREe6MH
for some reason it didn't let me post the link in the question.